# Update multiple subtitles photos in Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a system that after uploading multiple photos it generates a subtitles field for each photo, I want to update the database of these subtitles. How to do this. My table in database - tb_fotos_portfolio table (id, portfolio_id, legenda, arquivo).

Obs .: It would be only the part of UPDATE the subtitles

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_fotos_portfolio WHERE id_portfolio = $id";
    $query = $DB->Select($sql);
    if (count($query) == 0) { ?>

        <div class="box-body">
            <h3 class="text-center text-danger" style="margin: 140px 0;">Imagem não enviada!</h3>
        </div>

    <?php } else { ?>

        <div class="box-body no-padding">
            <ul class="users-list clearfix">

                <?php foreach($query as $item) { ?>

                    <li>
                        <a class="popup-link" href="../../../upload/portfolio/imagem/<?php echo $item['arquivo']; ?>">
                            <img src="../../../upload/portfolio/miniatura/<?php echo $item['arquivo']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $item['arquivo']; ?>"/>
                            <span class="users-list-name"><?php echo $item['arquivo']; ?></span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn btn-label btn-danger btn-xs" href="acoes.php?acao=deleteFotos&id=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>&arquivo=<?php echo $item['arquivo'];?>"><i class="fal fa-trash-alt"></i>Excluir</a>
                        <span class="users-list-name"><?php echo $item['legenda']; ?></span>

                        <form id="" action="acoes.php?acao=legendas_fotos" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="text" name="legenda[]" id="legenda" class="form-control" placeholder="Legenda" value="<?php echo $item['legenda']; ?>"/>
                    </li>

                <?php } ?>
            </ul><!-- /.users-list -->
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-label btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Atualizar Legendas</button>  
        </form>
```

acao.php

```
case 'legendas_fotos':

    $legenda = $_POST['legenda'];

    ...

    $sql = "UPDATE tb_fotos_portfolio SET legenda= $legenda ";
    $vCampos = array('id'=>$id);
    $DB->Execute($sql, $vCampos);

    // Volta para o form
    header("location:form.php?id=" . $id);

    exit;
break
```

Comment: Where do you want to store the subtitles? There is no column in your database for subtitles

Comment: In legenda column (legenda is subtitles in Brazilian language)